# Passing variables to injected services to use as decorator argument

Tags: angular, inheritance, decorator

I have an Angular project that uses services that very often repeat themselves with the typical create/read/update/delete/read-list-of-all-entries. I also very often want to manipulate received data in similar ways after receiving it. So I wrote decorators that use `apply` which "transform" the data in a way determined by the parameter passed to them (the parameter is always an object class).

In normal use this looks like this:

```
//rule.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RuleService {

  rulesUrl: string = `${Constants.wikiApiUrl}/rule/`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  @TransformObservable(RuleObject)
  getRule(pk: number): Observable<Rule>{
    return this.http.get<Rule>(`${this.rulesUrl}/${pk}`);
  }
}
```

This happens a lot, so I want to write a parent-service that I can extend:

```
//generic-object.service.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class GenericObjectService{
  baseUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public objectClass: any,
  ) {}

  @TransformObservable(this.objectClass) //This line won't work
  read(pk: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${pk}`);
  }
}
```

The issue is that I can't use "this" for a decorator parameter, it doesn't exist at the time of parsing IIRC. But is there a way I could pass the decorator-parameter to my injected service somehow so that it may be used by the decorator?

Find below also the "TransformObservable" decorator:

```
export function TransformObservable(modelClass: any){
    /**Decorator to apply transformObservableContent */
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor){

        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function(){
            const observable = originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            return transformObservableContent(observable, modelClass);
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword will not be available outside of function scopes. However, you may define the needed object as a field/property in same class and in the decorator annotation, you may just pass a string that decorator function will lookup, or pass in an actual object reference.

In the decorator, check the argument that was passed to the annotation:

```js
if(typeof modelClass === 'string'){
  // lookup a property in decorated class definition
  modelClass = target[modelClass]; // or, this[modelClass]
}else {
  // assume modelClass is the needed object
}
```

This will allow you to use:

```js
@TransformObservable('propertyName');
// or
@TransformObservable(someObjectReference);
```

*Distinction between `target` and `this`:*

The `target` passed to decorator function is the object *that defines the class* where the decorator is used. It will have all the properties and methods defined in the class and can be used to retrieve them as shown above. However `target` is not the runtime `this` you would generally use inside the class methods. Its only the replacement method (`descriptor.value`) that will have `this` available inside it, like original method.

Hence, if you really need `this` and not just the decorated class definition, you must move all the code **inside** the replacement function `descriptor.value`. There you have access to `this` as well as all the parameters that are passed to the decorator and the decorator factory.

Comment: Ohhh, so target = the object within which the decorator is written. "this" = ... I am actually not quite sure which context "this" inside of the decorator represents at that point. The child service that starts the call?

Comment: Could it be that the way you have edited to now is incorrect, I wrote my reply when `this` was still written as `target` (for future readers). `this` in `TransformObservable` is undefined, `target` does include an object that seems to be the object that the decorator is written inside of, aka `GenericObjectService`. However, for some reason the properties of GenericObjectService don't show up in that object, only the functions do.

Comment: @PhilippDoerner Updated in answer.

Comment: Ahh, I finally understood that the check for modelClass must happen in the anonymous function that I put into descriptor.value. For the errant reader I'll throw your suggestion put into practice as another solution below, but yours will stay the accepted answer.

Comment: @PhilippDoerner True. You have to move the code inside the replacement function and do the checks there, and you can use `this` there.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @S.D. 's answer I finally understood what he was trying to say all along: You have access to `this` inside the anonymous function that you put into descriptor.value. So for my decorator to be able to properly do this, I must access `modelClass` from inside that anonymous function using `this` and I'm good to go. Here is what the solution from S.D. looks like put into practice:

```
export function TransformObservable(modelClass: any){
    /**Decorator to apply transformObservableContent */
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor){

        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function(){
            const observable = originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);

            //If the decorator argument was not a class but instead a property
            // name of a property on the object that uses the decorator that 
            // contains the class, update the modelClass variable
            const decoratorArgumentIsProperty = ["String", "string"].includes(typeof modelClass);
            if(decoratorArgumentIsTargetProperty){
                modelClass = this[modelClass];
            }

            return transformObservableContent(observable, modelClass);
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```